# Passing instances of a class to a constructor of a different class C++

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

Why can't I pass the instance of one class (Class1) to the constructor of a different class (Class2), instead I have to create a new Class1 object in the declaration of the Class2 object.

```
 class Class1{
    public:
        int x;
        Class1(){

        }
        Class1(int x){
            this -> x = x;
        }
};

class Class2{
    public:
        int y;
        Class1 cInst;
        Class2(int y, Class1 cInst){
            this -> y = y;
            this -> cInst = cInst;
        }
};
Class1 a  = Class1(0);

Class2 b = Class2(1, a); //error message here : "no instance of constructor "Class2::Class2" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (int, Class1)"
Class2 c = Class2(1, Class1(0)); //this works
```

My declaration here for c works but fails for b. I've tried playing around with copy constructors but with no success. Is it possible to pass instances of one class to the constructor of another in c++?

Comment: Compiles fine here. See https://ideone.com/vKAaRG

Comment: Hmm could it be something with my compiler then? Im using gcc

Comment: No, it really couldn’t be. Try copy-pasting that code into a new source file and compiling it. Then look for differences between that and the code you’re having problems with.